# Trigo Study plan

Tags: trigonometry

In what order of topics is probably the most effective in learning trigonometry for starters... where should I first start? and steps in between to De Moivre's Theorem (which is the last topic)... just confused and I want a map so I could prepare in the exam without getting lost into different topics.

Comment: What exam are you preparing for?

Comment: Most people (at least in the US) don't study trigonometry as an independent subject.  They study it in the broader context of "precalculus".  So to learn trigonometry, I'd say just pick up a textbook on precalculus from your local library/ used book store and start working through it.  There probably won't be more than $2$ or $3$ chapters on trig in it, so it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: It's for an exam where you get advanced credits for that subject... the trigo subject is also a prerequisite for Calculus intro... Right now , I'm currently studying college algebra / in fact just reviewing... but yeah I've studied Trigonometry too and I find it confusing especially the different the different Identities so I need a map to not get swayed into different directions... Thanks for the answers :).. I'll probably try the precalculus one.. it's for a college course and I want to lighten up my load and finish this math hahah since I find it completely unrelated to what I'm taking

Comment: "Precalculus" is an obnoxious term since it refers to a place in a curriculum rather than to a subject. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't see how that makes it obnoxious.  Besides, it covers a [fairly well established set of topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precalculus#Contents).